# Quotient group inclusions

Tags: group-theory

Let $G_i < G$, and $Z_i < G$ be normal subgroups of $G$ and consider the following inclusion for the commutator: $[G,G_i]<Z_i$.

How can we see that $G_iZ_i/Z_i<Z(G/Z_i)$, where $Z(\dots)$ denotes the center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $\;x\in G\;,\;\;g_i\in G_i\;,\;\;z_i\in Z_i\;$ :

$$x^{-1}(g_iz_i)^{-1}x(g_iz_i)=x^{-1}z_i^{-1}g_i^{-1}xg_1z_i=x^{-1}z_i^{-1}x\overbrace{\left(x^{-1}g_i^{-1}xg_1\right)}^{\in Z_i\,,\,\,\text{given}}z_i\in Z_i$$